# libp2p adding single external public node to private network peers

Tags: libp2p

I have a libp2p network in a private network and the nodes can find each other using multi cast. Now I have to add a single external node with a known DNS/IP address. I only need to add this single node and do not need any other discovery mechanisms. How is it possible to get connected to this single external node? I'm using Go.